# SSL operation failed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

i don't understand what have changed, i have used this smtp protocol before and everything works fine. runs perfectly and sends an email to the user but right now when i run it some kind of error shows. it has the exact same laptop nothing was touched in my server. what is the problem here?

> Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

disabled my avast permanently, i cleared the email ports. is it okay to have no value in openssl.cafile?

[image]

[image]

email.php

```
<?php
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'; 
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = '*********'; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '*********'; 
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['dsn'] = TRUE;
    $config['validate'] = TRUE;
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '30';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard
    ?>
```

controller

```
$this->load->library('email');//path application/config/email.php
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->attach($image);
$cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($image);
$message_right = '<img src="cid:'.$cid.'" alt="gfc-logo" style="width:30%;margin-left:30%;"/>';

$this->email->to($emailAdd);
$this->email->from('*********@gmail.com', 'KFC');
$this->email->subject('Resetting your gfc login password');
$this->email->message($message_header.$message_left.$message_right.$message_footer);
if ($this->email->send()) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('category_success', 'A link to reset your password has been sent to <a>"'."$emailAdd".'"</a>. If you dont see it, try to check on your spam forlder.');
}else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('category_error', 'Their is some problem sending <a>"'."$emailAdd".'"</a> to our SMTP_SERVER, Please try Again.');
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());exit;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the cert expired?

Comment: @BrianGottier how to update those? where can that be found?

Comment: That all depends on your server. What is the server type, and do you have admin access?

Comment: i used a localhost xampp server with no admin access

Comment: https://benohead.com/generating-new-certificate-xampp-windows/

Comment: @BrianGottier would it help if i re-install my xampp server?

Comment: I can't answer that. It couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @BrianGottier i already followed the generation and installation of new cert and it was a success, but unfortunately my problem was never solved. it has same error.

Comment: Even though this is referencing Linux, your answer may be the same: https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=70278